# Unable to debug code for 686E on Codeforces

Tags: c++, debugging

I have been trying [this](http://codeforces.com/contest/686/problem/E) problem for a while, but haven't been successful.

The problem is "Given a set of source points in the plane, find a point (with integer coordinates) such that the maximum Manhattan Distance to any of the source points is minimized".

I found a [very similar problem](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32001/dashboard#s=p2) on Google Code Jam, which I successfully solved using their Contest Analysis.

My approach is very similar to the solution for the Code Jam problem, adapted to fit the integer constraint in the CodeForces problem.

As far as I can see from the details of wrong test cases, my answer "isn't good enough", i.e., there exists a point with smaller maximum distance.

Unfortunately, I cannot link my code (2 links limit), so I have copy-pasted it below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

#define setMax(a, b) (a<b)?(a=b):0
#define setMin(a, b) (a>b)?(a=b):0

using namespace std;

const int N = (int)1e5;
const long long LL_UP = (long long)9e18;

struct point
{
    long long x, y, z;

}s[N];

bool doesAnswerExist(long long c, int n, point &ans)
{
    long long A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H;
    A = C = E = G = -LL_UP;
    B = D = F = H = LL_UP;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        setMax(A, s[i].x + s[i].y + s[i].z - c);
        setMin(B, s[i].x + s[i].y + s[i].z + c);
        setMax(C, -s[i].x + s[i].y + s[i].z - c);
        setMin(D, -s[i].x + s[i].y + s[i].z + c);
        setMax(E, s[i].x - s[i].y + s[i].z - c);
        setMin(F, s[i].x - s[i].y + s[i].z + c);
        setMax(G, s[i].x + s[i].y - s[i].z - c);
        setMin(H, s[i].x + s[i].y - s[i].z + c);
    }

    if (A > B or C > D or E > F or G > H)
        return false;

    long long xMin = ceil(max((G+E)/2.0, (A-D)/2.0)), xMax = floor(min((B-C)/2.0, (H+F)/2.0));

    if (xMin > xMax)
        return false;

    for (ans.x = xMin; ans.x <= xMax; ++ans.x)
    {
        long long ypz = max(A-ans.x, C+ans.x), ymz = max(ans.x-F, G-ans.x);

        if ((long long)fabs(ymz + ypz) % 2 == 1)
        {
            if (ypz < min(B-ans.x, D+ans.x))
                ++ypz;

            else if (ymz < min(ans.x-E, H-ans.x))
                ++ymz;

            else
                continue;
        }

        ans.y = (ypz+ymz)/2;
        ans.z = (ypz-ymz)/2;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void binSearch(long long l, long long r, int n, point &ans)
{
    if (l == r)
    {
        doesAnswerExist(l, n, ans);
        return;
    }

    long long mid = (l+r)/2;

    if (doesAnswerExist(mid, n, ans))
        binSearch(l, mid, n, ans);

    else
        binSearch(mid+1, r, n, ans);
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    int t, n;

    cin >> t;

    while (t--)
    {
        cin >> n;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            cin >> s[i].x >> s[i].y >> s[i].z;

        point ans;
        binSearch(0, (long long)3e18, n, ans);

        cout << ans.x << ' ' << ans.y << ' ' << ans.z << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here's a [link](http://codeforces.com/submissions/Cerberus97) to the details of my submissions. (Please tick the show unofficial check box to see them)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself, I must say, it was the stupidest mistake I've ever made.

I was stupidly assuming that dividing an integer by 2 would give me floor(x/2), but as I just found out, that isn't true for negative numbers, as int(-2.5) will give -2 and not -3.